# Ввод элементов стека через консоль

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Как реализовать ввод элементов стека не статичными данными, а с помощью ввода через консоль? Ну, т.е. через диалоговое окно например: "Введите стек:".

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

class Stack    // класс стек
{
private:
    static const int MAX = 10; // размер
    int st[MAX];
    int top;
public:
    Stack()
    {
        top = 0;
    }
    void push(int var) // функция вставки
    {
        st[++top] = var;
    }
    int pop()
    {
        return st[top--];
    } // функция вывода
};

int main()
{
    Stack s1;

    s1.push(11);
    s1.push(22);
    s1.push(33);
    s1.push(44);
    s1.push(55);
    s1.push(66);
    cout << s1.pop() << endl;
    cout << s1.pop() << endl;
    cout << s1.pop() << endl;
    cout << s1.pop() << endl;
    cout << s1.pop() << endl;
    cout << s1.pop() << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - просто в цикле вызывать `std::cin >> value` , до тех пор, пока не будет введён недопускимый символ (возможно, имеет смысл считывать строки, а уже их парсить в int - иначе сложно сделать условие выхода из цикла).

Тут недавно было несколько вопросов на тему стека, там были примеры реализации меню. На мой взгляд - это не лучший вариант, но рабочий.

Другой вариант - реализовать командный режим работы. Что-то вроде

```
create "stack1"
add "stack1" 3
create "stack2"
add "stack2" 8
add "stack2" 15
print "stack2"
pop "stack2"
print "stack2"
```

Сами стеки можно хранить в `std::map` с именем в качестве ключа. Команды проще всего читать построчно, т.е. `std:cin.getline()`, команды можно парсить либо обычными вложенными if-фами, либо использовать `std::map<std::function<void(const std::string&)>>` по принципу "извлекаем команду - ищем в карте функцию, соответствующую команде - вызываем функцию, передавая ей аргументы этой команды (остаток строки)".

Answer (score 0):

У вас массив неинициализирован изначально, а первый элемент массива  занимает память и никогда не используется, и когда используете массив, всегда нужно обработать выход за пределы:
По этим причинам я немного переделал ваш код и добавил то, что вас интересует

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Stack    // класс стек
{
private:
    static const int MAX = 100; // размер
    int st[MAX];
    int top;
public:
    Stack() : top(0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) // инициализирум массив
            st[i] = 0;
    }
    void push(int var) // функция вставки
    {
        if (top < MAX)
            st[top++] = var;
        else  
            std::cerr << " error: Stack is full!  ";        
    }
    int pop()
    {
        if (top)
            return st[--top];
        else {
            std::cerr << " error: Stack is empty!  ";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    bool isFull() const { return top == MAX;}  // Stack overflow?
    size_t size() const { return top; }        // количество введенных элементов
    friend istream& operator >>(istream& is, Stack& s)
    {
        int k = 0;
        while (is >> k  && !(s.isFull())) {     // вводим из cin пока стэк не полон
            s.push(k);
        }
        return is;
    }
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Stack& s)
    {
       int k = s.top;
       if (k)    // если стэк не пустой выводим все вводимые начиная с последнего
       for (int i = k - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
           os << s.st[i] << ' ';
       else
           os << "error: Stack is empty!";
       return os;
    }
};
```

теперь можно спокойно работать со стэком, а также осуществить ввод и вывод через  консоль  (как вы сказали)

```
int main()
{    
    Stack s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хочу заметить, что цикл  `for(int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) st[i] = 0` в конструкторе стека не имеет смысла, достаточно инициализации индекса вершины `top(0)`.

Comment: @LShadow77, уместно, но....
 Если на то пошло, то такой класс в целом не имеет смысла. Ответ отражал что нужно делать, а не как нужно делать.

Comment: как нужно делать - тоже часть ответа;)

Comment: прекрасно, ждем ваших ответов как нужно делать. Я только буду рад за сайт и за пользователей.

Comment: благодарю, стараюсь по мере своих сил))